# What is the antonym of 'prime time' for television?

Tags: antonyms

I am looking for a word that has opposite meaning of 'prime time' in television (like early morning news...).

Comment: "Non-prime time".

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the exact opposite of prime time is, "The graveyard slot."

> [Dayparting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dayparting)
>
> After the late night shows, programming varies; this time slot between
> approximately 2:00 and 6:00 a.m. is known as the "graveyard slot" due
> to the extremely low numbers of viewers.
>
> Wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "**off-peak viewing time**" or **off-peak slots**.

- Definition of off-peak :  Not in the period of most frequent or heaviest use.
- Example: travelers who take advantage of off-peak fares ...

Answer (score 0):

Daytime.  There's a separate event of the Emmys (television awards), called "[The Daytime Emmys](http://emmyonline.com/daytime)."  The "regular" Emmys are for prime time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, during the daylight hours, such tv is simply called ***daytime tv***. That term has a derogatory element because daytime tv tends to have a much smaller audience, much less funding as a consequence and, accordingly, be of a much lower quality.

In the evening, prime time tv tends to end at what's called the *watershed*: a time after which it's permitted to broadcast adult (or more risqué) content. Hence, I think that a term for the type of tv you seek might be ***post-watershed***.